# Set margin to print in Java code

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to print a JPanel...and I have working code. But the problem is, it's printing the JPanel with broad magin from 4 sides... Plz someone check my code. And suggest me,how can I change my code which will be suitable for a4 size paper with minimum margins. And this code for actioperformed

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat preformat = pjob.defaultPage();
        preformat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
        PageFormat postformat = pjob.pageDialog(preformat);

        if (preformat != postformat) {
            RepairBill r=new RepairBill();
            r.setVisible(false);
            pjob.setPrintable(new Printer(r.r), postformat); //r.r is the object for JPanel
            if (pjob.printDialog()) {
                try {
                    pjob.print();
                } catch (PrinterException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Code for printer class

```
public static class Printer implements Printable {
    final Component comp;

    public Printer(Component comp) {
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int page_index) throws PrinterException {
        if (page_index > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        // get the bounds of the component
        Dimension dim = comp.getSize();
        double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
        double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

        // get the bounds of the printable area
        double pHeight = format.getImageableHeight();
        double pWidth = format.getImageableWidth();
        double pXStart = format.getImageableX();
        double pYStart = format.getImageableY();
        double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
        double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
        g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
        comp.paint(g2);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

[plz see the screenshot of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMhUn.png)

Comment: The code centers (`translate`) and `scale`s (not proportionally!). As the units are 1/72nds of an inch could set an absolute margin, but it should be at least be getImageableX/Y. And scale in both orientation by Math.min(xRatio, yRation).

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough idea about printing in Java. Will you please tell me, what should I change in this code?

Comment: I programmed it out. No big differences as you see.

Answer (score 0):

I have added margins: 1 inch horizontally, 0.5 inches vertically.

With a check that the margins are still printable (a 1 mm margin is not feasible).

The page size I did leave untouched as that is a physical device issue, whether someone has A4 or US Letter for instance. One may set it in the PrintJob, look into the API, the javadoc in the net.

Scaled is now done proportionally.

```
    // get the bounds of the component
    Dimension dim = comp.getSize();
    double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
    double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

    // get the bounds of the printable area
    double pHeight = format.getImageableHeight();
    double pWidth = format.getImageableWidth();
    double pXStart = format.getImageableX();
    double pYStart = format.getImageableY();
    double paperHeight = format.getHeight();
    double paperWidth = format.getWidth();

    final int INCH = 72;
    double vertMargin = 0.5 * INCH;
    double horMargin = 1 * INCH;

    // Check whether margins are enough, are printable.
    if (paperWidth - 2 * horMargin < pWidth) {
        pWidth = paperWidth - 2 * horMargin;
        pXStart = horMargin
    }
    if (paperHeight - 2 * vertMargin < pHeight) {
        pHeight = paperHeight - 2 * vertMargin;
        pYStart = vertMargin;
    }

    // Determine scaling
    double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
    double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;
    double ratio = Math.min(xRatio, yRation); // Proportional

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
    g2.scale(ratio, ratio);
    comp.paint(g2);
```

Comment: sorry sir. but i copied the above code.. but its not giving me appropriate output

Comment: You could give `g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);` a try, maybe the component is vertically larger than a page. Sorry it did not work out.

Comment: sir, i have just edited my post. plz checkout the screenshot of my output. this is the same output what i am getting after i copied your code and changed g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);

Comment: I cannot do more. Try start anew with `Graphics.drawLine, drawRect, drawString` to draw grid lines. And then look how to reach your goal.